# Need CSS effect when hovering over an image, to get another image and/or text to display above it

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, html, hover

I have 10 country flags on my company's website (VS 2010/vb/asp.net4.0).  Clicking a flag will display the website in that country's language for their entire session.

I would like to, when the client hovers over the flag, have a **mini-picture of that country** hover above and to the right of the flag.  So when they click on the German flag, a mini-map of Germany appears to the **upper right** -- and I'll z-index it so it goes above the table row above it -- and in addition to the image, it'll say something like, "Deutch" or "View this website in German" (in German, of course).

```
                   **Images of countries here when hovering**
       Flag1  Flag2  Flag3  Flag4  Flag5  Flag6  Flag7  Flag8
```

For someone like me who's not great at CSS, is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is perhaps one of those things which you might be best to apply the "KISS" approach! (keep it simple stupid) I think in general people are well aware of their flag so adding in extra stuff will either confuse people who expect it to work in a certain way or offend them!

Comment: That's a good point, Treemonkey  I'm going to look at these solutions and see if I can get any to work on my website, but I do think you make a good point.  I'll be in touch soon after I check out these solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose you are using a list

```
<a class="flagbutton">
  <img src="/flag1"/>
  <img class="map" src="/flag1map"/>
</a>
<a class="flagbutton">
  <img src="/flag1"/>
  <img class="map" src="/flag1map"/>
</a>
<a class="flagbutton">
  <img src="/flag1"/>
  <img class="map" src="/flag1map"/>
</a>

.map{
display:none;
}
a.flagbutton:hover .map{
display:block;
}
```

you can add extra css to do the positioning in the .map bit!

Comment: Thanks Tree, for your time in responding!   I think the problem with this solution is because my code is written in asp.net, not standard html, like this:            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
           CommandArgument="en" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click">
         <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagus.png" CssClass="item" tooltip="View this website in English"/>
        </asp:LinkButton>

Comment: you can use this much the same i expect I will update answer to suit this problem! so here you will have 1 image for the flag and one for the hover over image both within the anchor tag

Comment: I have updated the answer above hope you can implement in this way!

Comment: That was unbelievable, Treemonkey!  You're a genius!  I had to position the top to 120px and the right to 220px, and I followed your instructions, and it worked PERFECTLY!  Chrome, FF, IE, all good to go!  I sincerely appreciate your help in taking the time -- thank you VERY much!

Comment: And I agree with KISS ... sometimes less is more, but I'm sorry -- your solution was WAY too cool, and I have to use it on our engineer company's website!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple to do with just CSS, Javascript isn't required at all. There are lots of details, but the basic pattern is to put your images inside the same element as the flag. Let's call it `.flag`. Set the country images to `display:none;`. Then, set the `.flag:hover img` to `display:block;`. That will make the image appear only when hovering on the flag.

You'll have to set the position of the flag element to relative, and the position of the country image to absolute. That will allow you to set the top and right positions of the image to where you want.

Comment: Thank you Nate -- I appreciate the response!  Along with others, I'm still trying to implement some type of solution -- and all advice helps.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jquery as that will allow you to get the display of the image/text when you hover.  CSS will be used to position and format image or text.

Here is a good reference to start with.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: I have implemented jquery on my website, Robert, but I'm not sure the one in the example you linked, and it might be a little too intricate for someone like me, who's not too intelligent.  But thank you very much for taking the time to attempt to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in CSS but if you need animations you need JS. Here is the code for the one without the anims.

**HTML**

```
</ul>
   <li class="item">
      <img src="flag.jpg" />
      <img src="pic.jpg" class="pic" />
   </li>
   <li class="item">
      <img src="flag.jpg" />
      <img src="pic.jpg" class="pic" />
   </li>
   <li class="item">
      <img src="flag.jpg" />
      <img src="pic.jpg" class="pic" />
   </li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
   position:relative; /*Needed for pos:absolute below*/
}
.pic {
   display:none;
}
.item:hover pic {
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: I liked your solution, Ege, and I tried it.  My code is written not in html li and ul, so I couldn't get it to work properly (without displaying the image intended for mouseover only to show up all the time) --           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
           CommandArgument="en" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click">
         <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagus.png" tooltip="View this website in English"/>
         <img class="map" src="images/ussonfacebook.png" alt=""/>
        </asp:LinkButton>   ..... But thanks for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/UHZzJ/

You can substitute the list with `<div>`'s as well or as your structure requries. The line which says 'View this website in German' needs to be in a sub-div adjacent to the link and be absolutely positioned to the parent `<div>`.

Forgot to add, a `li:hover` will not work in IE6. Only `a:hover` is allowed for. In that case you'll have to put the div within the `<a>` (setting the `display:block`). If you're open to JQuery, there are more elegant solutions - http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html, http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that, Sagar -- I appreciate your help!  I think it's difficult to implement that solution (I tried) because my code is not written in html ul and li, but written like this:           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
           CommandArgument="en" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click">
         <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagus.png" tooltip="View this website in English"/>
         <img class="map" src="images/ussonfacebook.png" alt=""/>
        </asp:LinkButton>